# A UI console to check the depth of ibm message hub

Tags: ibm-cloud, message-hub

I have connected a producer to IBM Message Hub in Bluemix. How could I get a view of topic and its depth in message hub. Is there a web console where i can see messages count?

Thanks
Raj

Comment: Raj, what have you tried so far? Have you checked the docs - https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/MessageHub/index.html#messagehub? Other resources to check would be the Apache Kafka docs - http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html, IBM developerWorks and samples on GitHub.

Comment: Hi, we are looking for adminitration type console where admin can monitor message hub topics. Metrics like total consumers connected, topic depth, partitions per topic, ingress/egress rates, retension policies etc. I have gone through message hub docs on bluemix, but that does not provie that. I am currently evaluating Kafka docs.

Comment: I sent a note to our Message Hub guy to make sure he sees your question.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really the concept of a topic depth in Kafka, as Kafka is a commit log. You're not reading messages off a queue, you're reading messages from a point in the log, you can specify where in the log you start, and reading a message doesn't remove it from the log. So, the number of messages available is not affected by a read operation, but an individual consumer's place on the log moves.

Partitions per topic can be found from the Message Hub UI that lists the topics names, as well as the retention policy for the topic.

Input/Output rates for each topic are available in the Grafana tool.